# Safe way to use callbacks and heap objects with P/Invoke

Tags: c#, .net, pinvoke

The following sample is from [Microsoft's documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.gchandle(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
public delegate bool CallBack(int handle, IntPtr param);

public class LibWrap
{
  // passing managed object as LPARAM
  // BOOL EnumWindows(WNDENUMPROC lpEnumFunc, LPARAM lParam);

  [DllImport("user32.dll")]
  public static extern bool EnumWindows(CallBack cb, IntPtr param);
}

public class App
{
  public static void Main()
  {
    Run();
  }

  [SecurityPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, UnmanagedCode=true)]
  public static void Run()
  {
    TextWriter tw = System.Console.Out;
    GCHandle gch = GCHandle.Alloc(tw);

    CallBack cewp = new CallBack(CaptureEnumWindowsProc);

    // platform invoke will prevent delegate to be garbage collected
    // before call ends

    LibWrap.EnumWindows(cewp, GCHandle.ToIntPtr(gch));
    gch.Free();
  }

  private static bool CaptureEnumWindowsProc(int handle, IntPtr param)
  {
    GCHandle gch = GCHandle.FromIntPtr(param);
    TextWriter tw = (TextWriter)gch.Target;
    tw.WriteLine(handle);
    return true;
  }
}
```

There are two things that mystify me.

Firstly, the documentation of `GCHandle.Alloc` only talks about preventing a an object to be garbage collected. If that was all, you wouldn't need `GCHandle.Alloc`: Obviously in the sample, `tw` isn't going to be collected during the call to `EnumWindows` - there's a reference to it in the function scope.

The concern here is that one needs to make sure that it isn't *moved*. But the documentation of `GCHandle.Alloc` doesn't talk about that. So what's going on?

Secondly, what about the delegate? There may not be a problem in this sample, but what if the delegate is bound to an object (a lambda with a closure or a non-static method of a class)? In that case, one needs to take care of the delegate too, right? Is that another `GCHandle.Alloc(myDelegate)` or are there more things to consider?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Moving is not a concern. `GCHandle.ToIntPtr` promises to give you an integer value that you can, at a later date, pass to `GCHandle.FromIntPtr` to retrieve the original handle. That's all. If you need to stop the object moving in memory then you would have to pin it. But you don't actually need to pin the object, you just need to stop it being collected, and be able to retrieve it in your callback.

The delegate's lifetime is not an issue here because the p/invoke framework will make sure it is not collected during the external call to `EnumWindows`, as noted in the comment. If you pass a delegate to unmanaged code, and that unmanaged code holds a reference to the delegate, then you have work to do. You must ensure that the delegate outlives the unmanaged reference to it.

Comment: Ah, I don't need to pin it as it's not the unmanaged side of things that actually uses the reference, right? Only if the unmanaged side is dereferencing, pinning becomes necessary, correct? I still don't see why I wouldn't have to also pin the delegate (or rather the associated object) in the scenario you describe in the last two sentences.

Comment: The p/invoke marshaller guarantees that the delegate lives until the call returns. That's enough. The delegate object doesn't need to be pinned. The marshaller creates an unmanaged thunk (that calls the delegate) whose address is passed to the unmanaged code. The address of the delegate object is not passed to the unmanaged code of course because unmanaged code cannot directly call a delegate. Hence the need for the thunk.

Comment: And the thunk lives on the stack I presume. That makes sense. The only thing I still don't understand is what I have to do to pin objects in those cases where I do need to do so, ie. when the unmanaged code is dereferencing and it's doing so after the original call had returned. The `fixed` statement only pins something for a scope, so what do I use if I want to fix something indefinitely (or until I unfix it programmatically, rather)?

Comment: `GCHandle.Alloc(myObj, GCHandleType.Pinned)` - found it. Thanks for your time btw.

Comment: The thunk won't live on the stack. It will live on the heap. Needs to be in an executable heap and you don't want to make stack pages executable. Yeah, `GCHandleType.Pinned`, that's your guy.

Comment: But it's a special heap or at least the allocation is special in the way that the hunk can't be moved, right?

Comment: Obviously if the thunk was moved then everything would fall over!